# Why std::string seem to do something that std::is_convertible says isn't possible?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdstring

Why does `std::to_string` allow you to convert a `double` to `std::string` when `std::is_convertible_v<double,std::string>` is `false`? For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "If double is "
      << (std::is_convertible_v<double,std::string> ? "" : "not ")
      << "convertible to std::string then why is it possible to do this? "
      << std::to_string(3.141592) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there's no direct conversion between `double` and `std::string` perhaps? Can you elaborate what else you would expect please?

Comment: It's like asking why the presence of something like `int foo(std::string s) {return s.size();}` doesn't make `is_convertible_v<std::string, int>` return `true`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think my question is very clear.  `std::string` took a `double` and turned it into a string.  `std::is_convertible_v` just told me that's not possible.

Comment: @DimitrijeKostic: "* std::string took a double and turned it into a string.*" No; ***`std::to_string`*** did that. It's not `std::string`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Whoops, I meant to say `std::to_string` in my comment.

Comment: @DimitrijeKostic: I guess the issue at hand is why you think that a random function should affect the implicit convertibility of two types? That is, why do you believe that the existence of `to_string` should affect the answer to the question of convertibility? What's missing from your question is why you think that this behavior is wrong, confusing, surprising, or otherwise questionable.

Comment: @NicolBolas Because I didn't realize implicit convertibility was the underlying issue?  Your answer below explains that pretty well, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`is_convertible` is asking a very specific question about the language relationship between two types: can the source type undergo [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to the destination type? And `std::string` as a type has no implicit conversion into `double`, so the answer is no.

`std::to_string` is just a regular old function. It does not create any relationship between `std::string` as a type and `double`. Yes, it semantically converts a `double` into a `string`, but that is not an implicit conversion by the rules of the C++ language. As far as C++ is concerned, it's just a function.

C++ does not have a way to ask the question, "is there some function, somewhere, that can semantically convert an object of type `X` to an object of type `Y`?" And if that's the question you're trying to answer, there isn't really a functional way to get an answer.

---

It's important to note that the concept of implicit conversion is very special. Implicit conversions get to happen automatically in a lot of places. So if a type is implicitly convertible to another type, then that has a very strong meaning. If a string is implicitly convertible to a double, then that logically means that any function which takes a double also could be given a string.

Many languages consider this legitimate (though these languages usually are just using duck typing, so they don't typically have the concept of "a function which takes a double," merely "a function with takes a value"); C++ is not one of them. If you want to perform string-to-double conversion, C++ makes you spell it out.

Similarly, implicit conversion from one type to another is considered to be an intrinsic property of the types in question. That is, to create a user-defined conversion from `X` to `Y`, either `X` or `Y` must have a member function which defines this conversion. No third party code can *create* an implicit conversion between two types.

Answer (score 4):

`std::is_convertible_v<double,std::string>` being `false` means you can't do `std::string(3.141592)` (or more precisely `double` is not implicitly convertible to `std::string`), it has nothing to do with `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
std::string test() { return std::declval<double>(); }
```

is not well-formed code, as double cannot be converted implicitly,  which is part of definition what `std::is_convertible` checks.

Comment: This code is ill-formed because you're ODR-using `std::declval`